# How to add the answers

Tags: python

I have a piece of code from an exam paper that I'm doing for extra help.

The code I need help with:

```
def Denary(Hex):
    Result = ''
    ErrorFound = False
    DenaryEquivalent = ''
    EmptyInput=""
    for ThisHexDigit in Hex:
        if ThisHexDigit in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','A','B','C','D','E','F']:
            if ThisHexDigit == '0': DenaryEquivalent = '0'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '1': DenaryEquivalent = '1'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '2': DenaryEquivalent = '2'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '3': DenaryEquivalent = '3'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '4': DenaryEquivalent = '4'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '5': DenaryEquivalent = '5'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '6': DenaryEquivalent = '6'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '7': DenaryEquivalent = '7'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '8': DenaryEquivalent = '8'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '9': DenaryEquivalent = '9'
            elif ThisHexDigit == 'A': DenaryEquivalent = '10'
            elif ThisHexDigit == 'B': DenaryEquivalent = '11'
            elif ThisHexDigit == 'C': DenaryEquivalent = '12'
            elif ThisHexDigit == 'D': DenaryEquivalent = '13'
            elif ThisHexDigit == 'E': DenaryEquivalent = '14'
            elif ThisHexDigit == 'F': DenaryEquivalent = '15'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '10': DenaryEquivalent = '16'
            elif Hex==EmptyInput:
                print('Empty input, try again.')
            Result = Result + DenaryEquivalent
        else:
            ErrorFound == True
            print('You have made a mistake')

    def HexToDenary():
        Hexadecimal = input('Enter a hexadecimal number: ')
        Converted = Denary(Hexadecimal)
        print (Converted)
```

When run, there are no errors and the program works (this is only part of it). What I want to know is how I'd add the result instead of it appearing as a binary answer. For example if I enter 'BB', I get '1111' instead of 187.  It should be easy but I can't figure it out.

And I know this is an over complicated piece of code but it is what was given.

Comment: This code is not syntactically valid.

Comment: You probably need to convert a string to an integer with `int`.  For example `int('11')` converts the string `'11'` into the number `11`.  I'm not sure why you are using strings in the first place, though.  Also, when you are pasting code onto stack overflow, be careful with the indentation - obviously, this is especially important for Python.

Comment: I'm sorry, not getting this: hex BB is 187, not 22.

Comment: You should not use elif ThisHexDigit == '10' as thisHexDigit will never have more than one character which means the elif part would never be executed.

Comment: Ah yes my bad. Even so, it still isn't giving the correct outcome.

Comment: This code is what was *given* to you? By whom? I really hope it's not someone who is licensed to teach programming.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: yup, clarified the comment.

Comment: Unbelievable. Which university? I don't think I have ever seen a worse Python program :)

Comment: It is AS level and a specimen paper. 2007/2008 unofficial specimen paper.

Comment: Are you sure this is your up to date code? You say `BB` gives you `1111`, but when I run the method, I get `None`.

Comment: This is not my entire code. Maybe that is why?

Comment: @TimPietzcker A/AS level computing is notorious for its truly awful syllabus and exam papers (all boards).

Comment: @user1331579 I strongly recommend that you learn programming entirely separately from your A/AS level.

Comment: "code from an exam paper". REALLY? Fire your teacher! You're learning on REALLY BAD examples.

Comment: At first glance, I thought I was on DailyWTF...

Comment: Wait, the exam is to take badly-written WTF code that doesn't work at all and fix it so it works? Sounds like a great idea for preparing students for the real world to me... :)

Comment: -4 for code from an exam? This place is harsh...

Comment: @user1331579 I apologise on behalf of the site. The code is really awful. Of course the blame lies with the examiner who wrote this code and you’re getting the brunt of the (justified) anger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change 2 lines in your program

```
Result = ''
```

to

```
Result=0
```

and

```
Result = Result + DenaryEquivalent
```

to

```
Result = Result*16 + int(DenaryEquivalent)
```

Off course you can simplify it by using dictionary

```
>>> def denary(hex):
    denary_equivalent={'1':1,'2':2,'3':'3','4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'A':10,'B':11,'C':12,'D':13,'E':14,'F':15,'10':16}
    result = 0
    for this_hex_digit in hex:
        if this_hex_digit in denary_equivalent:
            result=result*16+denary_equivalent[this_hex_digit]
    return result

>>> denary('BB')
187
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works to an extent that it adds, but BB gives 22 instead of 187 (made a mistake in the question)

Comment: -1 - this is a terrible way of doing it. Why convert strings to ints when they can just be ints in the first place?

Comment: @user1331579: See my update. You just need to multiply the result by 16 before adding the new value

Comment: After you added the *16 it now works. BB gives 187. Thank-you.

Comment: `.keys()` is unnecessary. `if ThisHexDigit in DenaryEquivalent:` already does just that. You should also rename the variables. Uppercase is by convention reserved for classes.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your equivalents are strings, not integers, so they get concatenated, not added.

So to solve:

```
if ThisHexDigit == '0': DenaryEquivalent = 0
```

However, you are showing a really bad way of doing this. Naturally the best way would be to use Python's built in handling of different numerical bases (`int(hex_string ,16)`), however, presuming the aim of this is a programming exercise,  Instead of using a lot of if statements, using a `dict` would be appropriate.

```
hex_digits_to_dec = {"0": 0, ..., "F": 15}
```

A quick way of producing this is as follows:

```
hex_digits_to_dec = {k: v for (v, k) in enumerate('0123456789ABCDEF')}
```

Enumerate returns tuples of `(n, v)` where v is each value from the iterable (in this case a string) you pass in, and n is a number, counting from 0. We use a dict comprehension to take this, reverse the key and value, and make a dictionary. You could just write this out by hand if you found it easier or clearer.

Then we can just do:

```
hex_string = hex_string.upper() #Save ourselves any errors from lowercase hex strings.
result = 0
try:
    for digit in hex_string:
        result = 16*result + hex_digits_to_dec[digit]
except KeyError:
    print("You made a mistake, this is not a valid hexadecimal number.")
```

This loops through our hex string, multiplying the previous values by 16 (as we go along, each digit is worth 16 times less than the digit to the left of it), and adding our new digit's value.

It is also worth noting that [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends `CapWords` for classes, and `lowercase_with_underscores` for local variables.

My old answer used this instead:

```
for power, digit in enumerate(reversed(hex_string)):
    result += (16**power)*hex_digits_to_dec[digit]
```

We reverse the string to get the lowest value digits first, then enumerate them to tell us the position (and therefore the value) of the digit. We take 16 to the power of this (to get the value of `1` at that position), and then multiply that by the value of the digit, and add them all together.

This works, but it was pointed out it's a less efficient method.

Comment: This will still give you 22 as a result, not 187 for the input `BB`.

Comment: It seems better to write `result = result * 16 + ...` since `**` may be expensive; also can optimize as `result << 4`. Also, `enumerate('0123456789abcdef')` looks better.

Answer (score -1):

Your programme works with strings. `+` concatenates strings.

You need to convert your operands to numbers.

In addition, you should use a `dict` for mapping from one set of data to another:

```
dict((b,a) for a,b in enumerate(['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','10'])))
```

Note also that your programme doesn't perform the conversion correctly, because it doesn't raise each digit to the correct power.

Comment: This produces a ``Decimal: Hexadecimal`` ``dict``, when what is needed is the other way around. See my answer.

Comment: Yes, but the fundamental point is that it produces a dict, which I imagine the OP is not aware of.